# now After clicking other than this ._box_color state changed to false ,i need after clicking on colorpicker this state dont change to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Thats is my code in React functional component :**

```
import { HexAlphaColorPicker,HexColorInput} from "react-colorful";

const props = {
 title:'colorPicker'
}
export default function ColorPicker(){
  const [color, setColor] = useState("#ffffff");
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handlerOpenColorPicker = (e,id) =>{
    if(e.target.id !== props.title ){
         setIsOpen(false)
        }else if(id === props.title){
         setIsOpen(!isOpen)
         }else{
         return '';
         }
       } 
document.body.addEventListener('click',handlerOpenColorPicker);
const handler = (e)=>{
 setColor(e)
 setIsOpen(true)
} 
return(
  <>
    <h6>{props.title}</h6>
    <div class="select_color" id="alert_inputTextColor_Follows">
     {isOpen ?   
      <HexAlphaColorPicker color={color} onChange={(e)=>handler(e)} />
       :
      ''
     }
     <HexColorInput class="_text_color" color={color} onChange={setColor} prefixed alpha />
     <div class="_box_color" id={props.title} onClick={(e)=>handlerOpenColorPicker(e,props.title)} style={{backgroundColor:color}}></div>
    </div>
 </>
)
```

i need it to be closed after clicking anywhere except Colorpicker, except for the same element and Colorpicker.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the state from changing when clicking on the color picker, you can add a condition to check the target element's id before setting the state. In your current code, you are using the handlerOpenColorPicker function to handle the click event on the color picker and other elements. You can add a condition to check the target element's id before setting the state. Here's an example:

```js
const handlerOpenColorPicker = (e,id) =>{
    if(e.target.id !== props.title ){
         setIsOpen(false)
        }else if(id === props.title){
         setIsOpen(!isOpen)
         }else{
         return '';
         }
       }
```

when the user clicks on the color picker element, the event's target id will be "colorPicker", which matches the id of the color picker. So, the setIsOpen(!isOpen) condition will be triggered and the state will not change to false. But when the user clicks on other elements, the target id will not match the color picker's id and the setIsOpen(false) condition will be triggered, so the state will change to false.

It would be better if you use React's onClick event instead of adding event listener to document.body.
You can also add a ref to HexAlphaColorPicker and HexColorInput, and check if the event target is inside of the refs.
You can stop event propagation in the onClick function of HexAlphaColorPicker and HexColorInput to prevent the click event from propagating to parent elements.